# facebook comments (Facebook social plugin) load only after I refresh the page in rails 4 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook-social-plugins

I have a rails 4 app and I want to use the Facebook social plugin for comments. I have this code: 
in show.html.erb I have

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="my site name" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

in application.js:

```
( function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id))
            return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=644565478915600";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And after my opening body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

When I go to the page, the comments appear only after I refresh it. Why?

Comment: were you able to solve it? I'm having the same problem

Comment: I finally found the solution in another stackoverflow question: I removed Turbolinks gem and it worked properly. I think there is a way to make them work together bu i'm not sure I need this gem.

Comment: @misschoksondik - yes, that appears to be the only thing that actually works 100% of cases.  Turbolinks was a horrible thing to make 'on' by default, imo.

Answer (score 1):

Remover Turbolinks. Also you can install jquery Turbolinks gem and then in your application.js file add //require jquery Turbolinks and remove // require Turbolinks

Answer (score 0):

There's an official solution to this known problem. wich it seems to be generated by the use of turbolinks. It's described [here](http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html). What I did was to add the provided coffescript to my page related coffee file (events.coffee in my case, placed in app/assets/javascript) and it worked like a charm. There's even no need of the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` tag. Hope it helps!

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I'm building a blog and on the Post I had the same problem. I did not want to disable Turbolinks. So the solution was to add the following to my `show.html.erb`:

`<% if current_page?(YOUR PATH) %>
    <body data-no-turbolink="true">
      <% else %>
    <body>
 <% end %>`

On `YOU PATH` you have to add the following page where you want to disable Turbolink.

Worked like a charm!